# Open git tracked files inside editor

Tags: git

I'm trying to make a Vim command which opens all modified files tracked by Git.

The following command works if there is only one modified file (and fails if the current working directory is not a git repository).

Any pointers on how to e.g. loop the results of external command producing multiple lines?

```
command Git execute ":e `git diff --name-only`"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `args` command instead:

```
command G execute ":args `git diff --name-only`"
```

The first file should be opened, and if you run `:ls` after executing this, you should see other files listed as well. Or, as romainl notes, you don't need the `execute` at all:

```
command G :args `git diff --name-only`
```

The `argadd` command could be useful too. From [`:h args`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aargs):

```
:ar[gs] [++opt] [+cmd] {arglist}                        :args_f
                        Define {arglist} as the new argument list and edit
                        the first one.  This fails when changes have been made
                        and Vim does not want to abandon the current buffer.
                        Also see ++opt and +cmd.
                        {Vi: no ++opt}

:ar[gs]! [++opt] [+cmd] {arglist}                       :args_f!
                        Define {arglist} as the new argument list and edit
                        the first one.  Discard any changes to the current
                        buffer.
                        Also see ++opt and +cmd.
                        {Vi: no ++opt}


:[count]arga[dd] {name} ..                      :arga :argadd E479
:[count]arga[dd]
                        Add the {name}s to the argument list.  When {name} is
                        omitted add the current buffer name to the argument
                        list.
```

Comment: `:next` is another possibility. Also, `:execute` is not needed, here, so the command could be shortened to ```command! G args `git diff --name-only` ```. AArgh, backticks are hard.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you mur and romainl!